# Ionic cli 4 but ionic project is on 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

So I'm trying to create a new ionic 4 project, I installed the cli version 4

Cli version:
ionic -v command shows this line

```
 CLI 4.12.0
```

but once I created the project and checked package.json of the project I found this line :

```
"@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
```

this is a little bit confusing, but this means that my project runs under ionic 5 ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

The *cli* has nothing to do with the *@ionic/angular* version. You can use the latest *cli* version, but install the *@ionic/angular* version you'd like, doing this:

```
  npm i @ionic/angular@YOUR.VERSION.NUMBER
```

You can pick whatever version you'd like from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/angular). Just go to **Versions** tab.

**edit:** you may want to do this before downgrading if you don't start a fresh install:

```
npm rm @ionic/angular --save
```